# How to pass Ctrl+R to the git bash terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: bash, terminal, git, visual-studio-code

Right now while in git bash terminal inside VS Code if I press Ctrl+R nothing happened - VS Code awaits for the second key of chord:

[image]

Is it possible to instruct VS Code to pass the Ctrl+R key combination to the git bash terminal?

**Edit 1**

I added `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` to my settings:
[image]
But `Ctrl+R` is not forwarded just the same.

**Edit 2**

Here is what I added to my user settings:

```
    "terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true,
    "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
        "-workbench.action.reloadWindow",
        "-workbench.action.openRecent",
        "-workbench.action.terminal.runRecentCommand",
        "-workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInRecentFilesPicker",
        "-editor.action.rename",
        "-editor.action.toggleRenderWhitespace"
    ],
```

[image]

These are all the Ctrl+R key bindings I can see:
[image]

But Ctrl+R is not forwarded to the shell just the same:

[image]

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Nope. `Ctrl+R` is not forwarded after I enabled `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell`. I will post an update.

Comment: There are several changes suggested in that other question besides the one you note. Please try those as well and report.

Comment: @music2myear - could you elaborate? Because I do not see anything else. The only other option mentioned in the other question is `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` and it seems to be less potent than `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell`. But maybe I am wrong. If you could elaborate, then I could test it.

Comment: Everything is described there accurately. I don't know what else to explain, except from asking you to read it fully and carefully. As the option you mentioned is definitely not less potent, for example.

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 2**. Thank you.

Comment: Once again, read my entire answer, including the chord info at the end and the description of that setting. The screen that you showed is waiting for 2nd part of the chord. You can either disable chords altogether or rebind the 2 commands that start with Ctrl + R chord. No other workaround.

Comment: Ah, so what I missed is that just mentioning a command with the chord in `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` is not enough (because both commands are mentioned by me). You explicitly specify this in your answer. Deleting the **Toggle Render Workspace** key binding did the trick. The other one is conditional and does not pose a problem. Now it works. Thank you very much for your patience. The question is indeed a duplicate.